# Qt method returns object without full object definition

Tags: c++, qt, header, qt5

I'm having a hard time figuring out how the classes are defined in Qt.

I'll take the QT5 JSON API as an example:

QJsonValue is a class representing any JSON value. It can be converted to a QJsonObject, QJsonArray, or to the standard types like QString, int, etc.

Now, the QJsonValue header looks like this (I stripped non-relevant parts, the complete file is [here](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/json/qjsonvalue.h.html)):

```
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include <QtCore/qstring.h>

class QDebug;
class QVariant;
class QJsonArray;
class QJsonObject; // class is pre-declared

class Q_CORE_EXPORT QJsonValue
{
    QJsonValue(const QJsonObject &o);
    QJsonObject toObject() const; // how does this work without 
                                  // any info on QJsonObject class structure??
    // ...
}
```

What bothers me is that `QJsonObject` is pre-declared as an existing class, but I figure that without any information on the inners of the class, the `toObject()` method won't compile (although it doest, including only `<QJsonValue>` doesn't fail).

I'm not so sure about the const reference, since it might not need the full class description, but just the address.

Problem is, there is never an include of *QJsonObject.h* anywhere in the file.

Is this magic or what?

Comment: It is included in the qjasonvalue.cpp file.

Comment: How does the compiler knows, with only the header file,how much space to save for this QJsonObject on the stack? *Without any information on it??* In C, if you reference a structure without defining the entirety of it, it fails, am I right?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/553796/492336

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use forward declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration)

Comment: I'm really confused about the bit where a method that is declared as returning this incomplete type can still be compiled without the compiler knowing about the return type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include of the header is needed only if you define functions, but the function declarations (even ones that takes type parameters by value) only require forward declaration.

Comment: From the comments to the question and this answer, it seems that C++ took a step further in letting the programmer use the least amount of header possible. I didn't know that it was possible to return full blown objects without completely defining the structure of this object. I guess the compiler has to make sense of that at compile time.

Comment: @xgbi: A declaration just means "there is an X". A definition means "here's the X". The compiler really doesn't have to do a lot for declarations. At most, it puts in a notice "hey, I used X" for the linker to fix up.